# What is Perl's default hash implementation?

Tags: hash-function, perl, perl5.30

According to [`perldoc perlsec`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html#Algorithmic-Complexity-Attacks)

> **Alternative Hash Functions** The source code includes multiple hash algorithms to choose from. While we believe that the *default perl hash* is robust to attack, we have included the hash function Siphash as a fall-back option. At the time of release of Perl 5.18.0 Siphash is believed to be of cryptographic strength. This is not the default as it is much slower than the *default hash.*

What is the default perl hash function? From the context we can infer it's not SIPHASH?

Comment: Tangentially related, some old comparisons: https://github.com/rurban/perl-hash-stats https://github.com/rurban/smhasher

Comment: At the time that was written, it was Jenkins one-at-a-time. That ceased to be the case as of Perl v5.28.0

Answer (score 6):

From the [`INSTALL` file in the source,](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/4a5ab54a18679ab24ca03190884d326c2ca85288/INSTALL#L369)

> Since Perl 5.18 we have included support for multiple hash functions,
>   although from time to time we change which functions we support,
>   and which function is default (currently `SBOX`+`STADTX` on 64 bit builds
>   and `SBOX`+`ZAPHOD32` for 32 bit builds).

You can see that [default in the source code in `hv_func.h`](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/a19348e73ed5eba787edfbc7ae2e9b4db947ee64/hv_func.h#L20). So it seems for 64 bit builds it's StadtX "fast hash function" which is implemented in [`stadtx_hash.h`](https://github.com/Perl/perl5/blob/d9bfa782f8cc54abdbea9c0a91d1b25a9ab98736/stadtx_hash.h).

Comment: This was most recently changed in a major way in [Perl 5.28](https://perldoc.pl/perl5280delta#Default-Hash-Function-Change).

Comment: The default was Jenkins one-at-a-time prior to Perl 5.28.0.